# Formalizing intuition of search hardness

Tags: soft-question, computational-complexity

Basically, this is a search problem of an object that is promised to exist. Suppose we have an object that can be described completely and uniquely by $m$ properties (each n bits). Suppose a search algorithm is given the bits of k properties $k \lt m$ and value $v$ of a q-ary function of all properties $f(p_1, p_2, ..., p_m)$.
We want the algorithm to find the missing bits of the remaining $m-k$ properties that satisfies the given function value $v$. Intuitively, any search algorithm must determine the missing bits of the unknown properties which should require exponential steps for each n bit property. So exhaustive search is unavoidable.

Is there a known formalization of my intuition? Is there a hidden flawed assumption in my intuition?

P.S. All $m$ properties are independent of each other.

Comment: statement unclear: what is the range of the function? Is it binary? $q-$ary?

Comment: @kodlu k-ary function.

Comment: This doesn't seem easier than a general search problem. Also, you could specify how we know when we have found a solution?

Comment: @usul For instance, an object could be a binary tree satisfying the function $f$ and the given partial description ( k properties).